# random css properties apply different number to each box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

Click the text box twice to load the boxes first

Then you'll see that they load with random padding and margins on each load but I'm trying to get them different on each object but I'm stuck, anyone know how to accomplish this?

```
function randomMargin(){
        $('.box').each(function(){
            randomizeObject(this); 
        });
    }

    function randomizeObject(el){
        var randomnumber1=Math.floor((Math.random()*51)+50);
        console.log(randomnumber1);
        var randomnumber2=Math.floor(Math.random()*101 + 50);
        console.log(randomnumber2);
        $(el).css({"padding": randomnumber1+"px", "margin": randomnumber2+"px"});
    }
    randomMargin();
```

Also hoping the layout to be slightly more masonry-y haha, not sure why it's not laying it out in more of a puzzle format

Comment: Are you trying to make a rough grid of the boxes in random order?

Comment: not random order, just have the padding adjust the sizes randomly and the margin to scatter them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
randomizeObject(this);
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
randomizeObject($(this));
```